# How to set the request body in a json format

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to send a request body in a json format to an API. The docs state the body needs to be formatted like so:

```
//Request body needs to the contain a JSON object in the following format:

{  
  "delete_list":[  
    "8fcd1d68c82dd39d65ef8ea9a7948bbe",
    "8bca1d68c92dd39d65ef8ea9a7948bbe",
    "8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7948bbe",
    "8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe"
   ]
}
```

My attempted code seems to fail and I am not sure why. I've tried quite a few adjustments and nothing seems to work:

```
    $del = array("delete_list" => "[8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe]");
    $j = json_encode($del);


    $apiToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $httpHeadersArray = Array();
    $httpHeadersArray[] = 'Authorization: key='.$apiToken;
    $httpHeadersArray[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';


    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($j));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeadersArray);


    $res = curl_exec($ch);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($res);
    echo "</pre>";
```

My end result that I get back from the API is as follows:

```
{"status":"failure","message":"JSON malformed"}
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong with the code? It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try getting rid of `http_build_query` as it will encode vital JSON bits

Comment: `$del = array("delete_list" => "[8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe]");` need to be something like:- `$del = array("delete_list" => array("8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1) You're json encoding an object with a single string but you need to encode an object with an array.

2) You're using `http_build_query` which will urlencode the array arguments and break the JSON structure.

Do this:

```
    $del = array("delete_list" => [ "8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe" ]);
    $j = json_encode($del);


    $apiToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $httpHeadersArray = Array();
    $httpHeadersArray[] = 'Authorization: key='.$apiToken;
    $httpHeadersArray[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';


    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $j);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeadersArray);


    $res = curl_exec($ch);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($res);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! That's is what was happening. This is what happens when you code with two broken ankles and really good pain meds! Thanks @apokryfos

Answer (score 1):

Throw the header at the top

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Setting the header won't affect the cURL request at all.

Comment: dude, the result which he will output, definitely get affected, it does not matter CURL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are malforming the json or indeed the array

`$del = array("delete_list" => array("8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe"));
$j = json_encode($del);`

This is the correct way, you are passing the array as a string, which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> `json_encode()` returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.
>
> — [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/json_encode)

It returns a representation of a value.

```
print_r(array(
    "delete_list" => "[8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe]"
));
```

Prints:

```
{
    "delete_list": "[8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe]"
}
```

Whereas:

```
print_r(array(
    "delete_list" => array(
        "8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe"
    )
));
```

Prints:

```
{
    "delete_list": [
        "8bca1d69c82d939d65ef8ea9a7947bbe"
    ]
}
```